# Desired approach to fail in js (config) file(s)

Tags: karate

I am wondering if others have brought up this question as I could not find anything in my brief searches.

What is the recommended way to exit a test run, at the onset, if something in the config fails, such as authentication, reference to an external file, or missing or invalid value for an expected, passed, parameter, such as karate.env (devv versus dev)?

Current Options tried with no success so far but not a lot of time put into them, to be honest:

- try/catch blocks
- return null rather than a config
- break

Answer (score 0):

There is a new `configure abortSuiteOnFailure` setting you can experiment with. It is described as follows:

`defaults to false, to not attempt to run any more tests upon a failure`

So you could do your check, conditionally set this flag if your check fails, and then call `karate.fail()`.

And yes, knowing how to do a `try - catch` in JS can [give you more control](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1465#issuecomment-816871930).