# Is there a way to catch org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException in karate, while a (Java) feature step is failing?

Tags: java, exception, karate, feature-file, catch-exception

While I'm running karate feature files with java classes, the feature file step is failing with `org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException` and do we have a way to handle those exceptions?

Since there are couple of test cases which has java implementation and these are tested by karate features.
i.e., let's assume a java class & feature

Class

```
public class TestUtil{
 public static void execute(){
  // this value might be null for some use cases & unexpected
  Long unexepectedVal = SomeInternalClass.getValue(); 
  SomeInternalImpl.processAndValidate(unexepectedVal.toString());
 }
}
```

Feature

```
Background:
  * def TestUtil = Java.type("pkg")
Scenario:
  * eval TestUtil.execute()
```

While executing the feature file some use cases, I may get `NPE/ConnectionTimeOutException/Other Runtime exceptions` and but during the failures I've got `org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException` as a root exception & how can we **trace/print** the the **original exception** in **HTML report**?.

Trying to catch the `org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException` and trace the original exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JS try-catch block with the `eval` keyword. Here is an example that also shows how to use `karate.fail()` if you still want to fail the test.

```
* eval
"""
try {
  var TestUtil = Java.type("pkg.TestUtil");
  TestUtil.execute();
} catch (e) {
  karate.logger.error('failed:', e);
  // do your custom cleanup or logging
  karate.fail('failed because of: ' + e);
}
"""
```

For further reading: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2242

And also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75903894/143475

Besides this I have no suggestions, so if you want any improvements in Karate please consider contributing code.